# HowTo view text file from the bottom on *nix?

Tags: bash

I'm looking a simple command, like

```
$ less -{view_from_bottom_of_the_file_option} filename
```

or

```
$ vi -{start_viewer_from_the_bottom} filename
```

viewer, editor - what ever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vi + filename` (open the file filename at the last line)

or

`vi +lineNumber filename` (e.g. to open the file with filename at line 100, `vi +100 filename`)

Answer (score 1):

```
tac $file | less
```

will reverse the order of the lines

Comment: depends on the filetype. logfiles with one entry per line will read exactly the same (only reversed)

Comment: @joey: the original question used `less` as an example, which will also not dynamically update the displayed file. `tail -[fF]` is another obvious solution – but that really depends on the intention of the OP

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+[num]` command line option of vim.

```
+[num]  The cursor will be positioned on line "num" for the first
        file being edited.  If "num" is missing, the cursor will be
        positioned on the last line.
```

So to palce the cursor at the last line you can do:

```
vim + file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

tail -n [lines] [file]
will output the last [lines] of the [file]. When you add -f, the file will not be closed and you will see updates which are appended at the file.

Answer (score 1):

`less` (on linux, FreeBSD, MacOSX) has the `+` option to send initial commands to less. An example in the man page uses it exactly to start viewing the file at last line. Like this:

```
less +G filename
```